# Insert component in Controller action EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, components, ember-charts

well i need to insert a component when the user click on button, my code:

dash.hbs

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" {{action 'solisXTax'}}> Consul</button>
```

dash.js  //controller

```
actions:{ solisXTax(){ "theCode" }, }
```

and my componenet is ember-chart,

```
{{ember-chart type="Bar" 
    data=solsGraph 
    width=500 height=350 
    options=opcionesGrafica 
    legend=true}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are familiar with the handlebars conditionals, but you should read more about that in the [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/templates/conditionals/)

You can use a conditional like so:

```
//templates/application.hbs
<button class="btn btn-primary" {{action 'solisXTax'}}> Consul</button>
<hr/>
{{#if componentVisible}}
    {{ember-chart}}
{{else}}
    no component shown
{{/if}}
```

with the corresponding action in your controller

```
//controllers/application.js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  componentVisible: false,
  actions:{ 
    solisXTax(){ 
      this.toggleProperty('componentVisible')
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a1ce621eea9c12fe2446f0bb6afe6345?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.ember-chart.hbs) that showcases using an if statement to toggle your component.

You could also dynamically toggle between different components, where one could be a empty component, but that might be overkill for your use case.